# syso shortcut in android studio?

Tags: android, eclipse, android-studio, keyboard-shortcuts

I am missing the "syso" feature (from Exclipse) in Android Studio.

(Entering "syso", pressing Cmd+Space and "syso" will be changed to "System.out.println()".

How is it possible to do that in Android Studio.

Comment: why exactly do you want to use "System.out.println();"

Comment: The answer below is useless to me as I wanted to know how to view/edit those shortcuts (and not if I should or not use Log instead), so for others in the future: it's called Live Templates on Android Studio (preferences -> Editor -> Live Templates -> Java). Simply go there and edit it (ie, change to SYSOUT as I did)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It is sout, but I would recommend using Log instead so you are also able to put tag in your console.

Answer (score 3):

"**sout**" + ctrl + space